# Updates url, but the page doesn't refresh, How?

Tags: javascript

https://www.petersons.com/search/schools?searchtype=12&page=3&result=15&searchterm=art

In the given website, when I change the page no (say, 4), it updates the url header, page=4, but the page itself is not reloaded. Only the component of the page is refreshed.

How is this achieved?

Comment: [read all about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Thanks :) @JaromandaX

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have two ways.
basically, you can use [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), or you can investigate more about [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). hope you get what you need.